# Identify a numeric pattern in 3 consecutive rows and replace the first match

Tags: r, dplyr

For the outcome variable, I want to identify a pattern (1,1,1) in 3 consecutive rows and make a new variable first_instance where the pattern is replaced by (2,2,2). I also want to replace all the 1's which don't follow the pattern perviously described to 0.

Below is the code for the dataset followed by what I want to achieve. I have not been successful to accomplish this. Any help is much appreciated.

```
library("tidyverse")
d=tibble(
  ID = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a"),
  Val = c(8,7,5,4,3,2,1,0),
  outcome=c(1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1))

d=tibble(
  ID = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a"),
  Val = c(8,7,5,4,3,2,1,0),
  outcome=c(1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1),
  first_instance=c(0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a `data.table` solution ;

```
d1=tibble(
  ID = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a"),
  Val = c(8,7,5,4,3,2,1,0),
  outcome=c(1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1))

library(data.table)

setDT(d1)

d1[,consecutive:=rleid(outcome)]
d1[,consecutive:=.N,by=consecutive]
d1[,first_instance:=ifelse(consecutive==3,2,0)]
d1[,consecutive:=NULL]
d1
```

output;

```
  ID      Val outcome first_instance
  <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>          <dbl>
1 a         8       1              0
2 a         7       0              0
3 a         5       0              0
4 a         4       1              0
5 a         3       0              0
6 a         2       1              2
7 a         1       1              2
8 a         0       1              2
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt response. Being a newbie, I am not allowed to vote answers up, but I will do it once I get some street cred.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `zoo`'s `rollapply` function to perform rolling calculation.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

n <- 3

d %>%
  mutate(three_consecutive = rollapply(outcome == 1, n, all, fill = NA, align = 'left'), 
         three_consecutive = rollapplyr(three_consecutive, n, any, fill = FALSE), 
         first_instance = ifelse(three_consecutive, 2, 0)) %>%
  select(-three_consecutive)

#  ID      Val outcome first_instance
#  <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>          <dbl>
#1 a         8       1              0
#2 a         7       0              0
#3 a         5       0              0
#4 a         4       1              0
#5 a         3       0              0
#6 a         2       1              2
#7 a         1       1              2
#8 a         0       1              2
```